# How to split a field up and create columns in a new table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble figuring out how to split a field up and create columns with those values in a new table.

Here is an example of what my table looks like

[snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av8us.png)

Basically, inside of the keyhash column there are multiple values in there separated by carrots that I need to turn into their own columns in a new table. I don't really know how to get started on accomplishing that.

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide both sample data and desired results, see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Is that valid XML? You could use XQuery to query it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this to split a column of string to multiple columns.

`PARSENAME(object_name nvarchar(128),object_part int)` receives a string with `'.'` delimeter and can return the nth part of that string

```
select 
    tableNumber,
    currVer,
    KeyAnalysis,
    Replace(REPLACE(keyhash,'<',''),'>','.') as KeyHash,
    REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(Replace(REPLACE(keyhash,'<',''),'>','.')), 1)) AS [Column1]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(Replace(REPLACE(keyhash,'<',''),'>','.')), 2)) AS [Column2]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(Replace(REPLACE(keyhash,'<',''),'>','.')), 3)) AS [Column3]
from SOF
```

the results will be like this

| tableNumber | currVer | KeyAnalysis | KeyHash | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #(LC) | 21.0401 | Key is: Region row header then subregion if available | 704.Lessors Liability per $100 of limit of ins. | 704 | Lessors Liability per $100 of limit of ins | NULL |
| #(LC) | 21.0401 | Key is: Region row header then subregion if available | 704.Occ Liability per $1000 of Annual Gross Sales.Fountain Hills. | 704 | Occ Liability per $1000 of Annual Gross Sales | Fountain Hills |
| #(LC) | 21.0401 | Key is: Region row header then subregion if available | 704.Occ Liability per $1000 of Annual Gross Sales. | 704 | Occ Liability per $1000 of Annual Gross Sales | NULL |

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this. I actually tried something similar but had no luck. Looks like you hit it spot on.

Comment: you are  always welcome